# TableTools code giving DataTables warning message when application built with r.js

Tags: jquery-ui, requirejs, r.js

I am having a problem building an application that includes TableTools. I am using r.js and the build line is

```
E:\Software\nodejs\node r.js -o build.js
```

The build.js is

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    paths: {
            'jquery'  : 'jquery-1.9.1',
            'jquery-ui' : 'jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom',
            'jquery.dataTables': 'jquery.dataTables',
            'jquery.tableTools' : 'TableTools'
    },
    name: "build_main",
    out: "external.min.js",
    optimize: "none"
})
```

Note that I have flattened all of the directories to make it easier to investigate.

When I load my test application, I get the message

```
Warning: TableTools 2 requires DataTables 1.9.0 or newer ...
```

I am pretty sure that DataTables is correctly specified in the build. It would seem that when the check in the TableTools code is done DataTables doesn't seem to have been fully loaded/initialised. If I put a break point at the line

```
if ( typeof $.fn.dataTable == "function" &&
```

in external.min.js and then step through, it won't popup the warning. Datatables looks to have been correctly initialised just by putting in a breakpoint and stepping through. If I remove TableTools then everything loads fine - DataTables is there.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am running into the same thing.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you earlier - I have resolved this but only by not including it in the build and loading it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen due to several reason as mentioned below,

1. You are using previous versions of Data-tables.
2. Not mentioning data tables in the build.
3. Older browser version or browser not supporting data-tables.
4. Slow internet.